# Issues to compute and plot a function with some Fourier analysis

Tags: numerical-integration, fourier-analysis

I'm currently in an internship and I have to construct a model that involve Fourier transform of 2 orbitals. My issue is that when I run the programm, the function evluateton non numerical values : "[image]

I have then look on the website and found something about adding ?NumericQ in the definition of every integrand, but the problem remain and I'm out of solutions.
Here's my program : `

```
G[R_, \[Alpha]_, R0_] := Exp[-\[Alpha]*(R - R0)^2];
\[Alpha]1 = 1.0;
\[Beta]1 = 0.01;
R01 = 2.0;
s = -1;
t = -2;

G1[R_?NumericQ, \[Alpha]_, R0_] := G[R, \[Alpha], R01] ;

G2[R_?NumericQ, \[Alpha]_, R0_] := G[R + R01, \[Alpha], R01];

NG1 = NIntegrate[
   G1[R, \[Alpha]1, R01]*G1[R, \[Alpha]1, R01], {R, -4 R01, 4 R01}];

NG2 = NIntegrate[
   G2[R, \[Alpha]1, R01]*G2[R, \[Alpha]1, R01], {R, -4 R01, 4 R01}];

GN1[R_?NumericQ] := 1/Sqrt[NG1] G1[R, \[Alpha]1, R01];

GN2[R_?NumericQ] := 1/Sqrt[NG2] G2[R, \[Alpha]1, R01];

FT1[k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[GN1[R]*Exp[-I*k*R], {R, -100, +100}];

FT2[k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[GN2[R]*Exp[-I*k*R], {R, -100, +100}];

Fset[k_?NumericQ] := {FT1[k], FT2[k]};


vec1[k_?NumericQ] := {(E^(I*k/2) Sqrt[2 + 5 E^(I*k) + 2 E^(2 I*k)])/(
   2 + E^(I*k)), 1};

vec2[k_?NumericQ] := {-((
    E^(I*k/2) Sqrt[2 + 5 E^(I*k) + 2 E^(2 I*k)])/(2 + E^(I*k))), 1};

Ok1[k_?NumericQ] := Fset[k] . vec1[k]

Ok2[k_?NumericQ] := Fset[k] . vec2[k]

O1[R_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[Ok1[k]*Exp[-I*k*R], {k, -100, +100}, MinRecursion -> 4];

O2[R_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[Ok2[k]*Exp[-I*k*R], {k, -100, +100}, MinRecursion -> 4];

NO1 = NIntegrate[
   O1[R, \[Alpha]1, R01]*O1[R, \[Alpha]1, R01], {R, -4 R01, 4*R01}];

NO2 = NIntegrate[
   O2[R, \[Alpha]1, R01]*O2[R, \[Alpha]1, R01], {R, -4 R01, 4 R01}];

ON1[R_] := 1/Sqrt[NO1] O1[R, \[Alpha]1, R01];

ON2[R_] := 1/Sqrt[NO2] O2[R, \[Alpha]1, R01];


rho[R_] := 2*(ON1[R]^2 + ON2[R]^2);

drho[R_] := Derivative[1][rho][R];

tau[R_] := 2*(Derivative[1][GN1][R]^2 + Derivative[1][GN2][R]^2);

tauvw[R_] := 1/8*(drho[R])^2/rho[R];

DR[R_] := tau[R] - tauvw[R];

DR0[R_] := (3/10)*rho[R]^(5/3)*(3*\[Pi]^2)^(2/3);

ELF[R_] := 1/(1 + (DR[R]/DR0[R])^2);
```

I just started mathematica 2 weeks ago, I'm sorry if my programm is not that clear. My goal at the end is to Plot the function ELF but the time f computation is really long.

Comment: I am playing with your code. I think much of this can be done symbolically before resorting to numerically integration.  Questions: 1) Do you want to integrate for {k,-100,100}? Would you accept the full fourier transform (see FourierTransform) instead?   2) Are the integrations over R in NG and FT also approximations to an integral over {R,-Infinity,Infinity}.  If they are acceptable, the integrations over the infinite domain simplify things.

Comment: I have already changed the interval of integration from {-100,100} to  {-10,10} because my functions vanishes after this interval. I have try the function FourierTransform but it was worse.
You are right for NG and FT, they are approximation of integrals over the real axis, could you explain me why it would simplify things to integrate over infinite domain ?

Thanks for your answer in any case !

Comment: I'm so sorry, regarding the "non-numerical value" problem, I juste figured out that in the definition of NO1/2 I was giving 3 arguments to O1/2 instead of just one argument...
I wasn't aware enough my bad.

It don't change the fact that computation is taking too much time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a a beginning. When I have some more time, I'll come back and edit this.

**Second Edit at Bottom, I normalized your distance variable and made your problem symmetric around the origin.**

The objective is to turn as many of the integrals into closed form solutions and do fewer numerical integrations.

If you normalize your distances by R0, i.e., rho = R/R0, you will have one less parameter to deal with.

Your defs:

```
g = Exp[-\[Alpha]*(R - R0)^2]
g1 = g
g2 = g /. R -> R + R0
```

Things may simplify more if you make your functions symmetric around 0: use {-R0/2,R0/2}.  This might reduce the number of integrations by 2.

```
ig1 = Integrate[g1*g1, {R, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > 0]
```

gives a closed form solution. This is your NG1.
Likewise

```
ig2 = Integrate[g2*g2, {R, -Infinity, Infinity}, Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > 0]
```

The normalized versions also give closed form solutions.

```
gn1 = g1/Sqrt[ig1]
gn2 = g2/Sqrt[ig2]
```

Now the Fourier transforms

```
ft1 = Integrate[gn1 Exp[-I k R], {R, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > 0]
```

which is practically the same as

```
FourierTransform[gn1, R, k]
```

for the g2:

```
ft2 = Integrate[gn2 Exp[-I k R], {R, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > 0]
```

fset would be more symmetric with the symmetry advice above. You may find that the terms are identical.

```
fset = {ft1, ft2}

vec1 = {(Exp[I k/2] Sqrt[2  + 5 Exp[I k] + 2 Exp[2 I k]])/(2 + 
     Exp[I k]), 1}
vec2 = {-((Exp[I k/2] Sqrt[2  + 5 Exp[I k] + 2 Exp[2 I k]])/(2 + 
       Exp[I k])), 1}
```

This also gives a closed form solution:

```
ok1 = FullSimplify[fset . vec1, 
  Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals] && \[Alpha] > 0 && R0 > 0]
```

and this

```
ok2 = FullSimplify[ fset . vec2, 
  Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals] && \[Alpha] > 0 && R0 > 0]
```

one of the terms has a closed form integral

```
ok1[[1]] + ok1[[2]]
```

The first parts:

```
O1p1 = Integrate[ok1[[1]] Exp[-I k R], {k, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> Element[R, Reals] && \[Alpha] > 0 && R0 > 0]
O2p1 = Integrate[ok2[[1]] Exp[-I k R], {k, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[R, Reals] && \[Alpha] > 0 && R0 > 0]
```

are identical.

The other terms (ok1[[2]]) *may* have closed forms, but they take a while.  If they don't, then you will need to do a numerical integral here.  I'll try some more later.

tau is going to be a problem because you need to take a derivative of a numerical function.  It is likely that you will need to Interpolate and then take a derivative of the InterpolationFunction.

I'll try to do more and edit this later.

**Additional analysis with symmetry and scaling.**

```
g = Exp[-\[Alpha]*(R)^2]
g1 = g /. R -> rho - 1/2
g2 = g /. R -> rho + 1/2
ig1 = Integrate[g1*g1, {rho, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > 0]
ig2 =  Integrate[g2*g2, {rho, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > 0]
gn1 = g1/Sqrt[ig1]
gn2 = g2/Sqrt[ig2]
```

ft1 and ft2 are complex conjugates:

```
ft1 = Integrate[gn1 Exp[-I k rho], {rho, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > 0]
ft2 = Integrate[gn2 Exp[-I k rho], {rho, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> \[Alpha] > 0]
fset = {ft1, ft2}
```

simplify your vector

```
tmp = FullSimplify[(Exp[I k/2] Sqrt[
      2  + 5 Exp[I k] + 2 Exp[2 I k]])/(2 + Exp[I k]), 
  Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals]]
vec1 = {tmp, 1}
vec2 = {-tmp, 1}
```

the following integrals have a nice symmetry:

```
ok1 = Apart@
  FullSimplify[fset . vec1, 
   Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals] && \[Alpha] > 0 && R0 > 0]
ok2 = Apart@
  FullSimplify[ fset . vec2, 
   Assumptions -> Element[k, Reals] && \[Alpha] > 0 && R0 > 0]
```

Pick out similar terms:

```
firstTerm = ok1[[1]]
secondTerm = ok1[[2]]
```

Check:

```
ok1 == firstTerm + secondTerm
ok2 == firstTerm - secondTerm
```

The first term has a closed form solution:

```
firstIntegral = 
 Integrate[firstTerm Exp[-I k rho], {k, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> Element[rho, Reals] && \[Alpha] > 0]
```

The second term can be numerically integrated.

```
secondIntegral[ro_, alpha_] := With[{integrand = 
        secondTerm Exp[-I k rho] /. {\[Alpha] -> alpha, rho -> ro}},
      NIntegrate[integrand, {k, -Infinity, Infinity}]]
```

For example:

```
Plot[secondIntegral[x, 1], {x, -2, 2}]
```

We can create an interpolator so we can integrate or take a derivative later:

```
secondIntegralInterpolator = 
 Interpolation[Table[{x, secondIntegral[x, 1]}, {x, -20, 20, .01}]]
```

For example:

```
Plot[(firstIntegral /. \[Alpha] -> 1) + 
  secondIntegralInterpolator[rho], {rho, -20, 20}]
```

and

```
Plot[(firstIntegral /. \[Alpha] -> 1) - 
  secondIntegralInterpolator[rho], {rho, -20, 20}]
```

look symmetric.

If you want the derivatives of the interpolator, you can do this:

```
D[firstIntegral, rho] + Derivative[1][secondIntegralInterpolator][rho]
```

Comment: Woaw thanks a lot that very accurate. I was looking for a function that was doing the job of FullySimplify ! I'll try what you say and have a look on my results. In the end I'll have to change values of (s,t) and get a collection of plot of ELF for different values. At least, you helped me to get something that is working, let's hope the time of computation will become reasonnable.

Comment: after replacing everything with respect to what you wrote, the "firstIntegral" and "secondInterpolatorTerm"  are not working

Comment: , respectively they send back messages like "Integrate::idiv: Integral of E^(-I k rho) ft2 does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}." and "NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9 recursive bisections in k near {k} = {-3.14157}. NIntegrate obtained 0.00173036 -6.93889*10^-18 I and 0.00011782580630857768` for the integral and error estimates."

When I try to plot one of the functions I don't get any curves on the graph either as you could expect then.. How is it possible that it works for you and not on my computer ?

Comment: I’ll check and make sure I can run it tomorrow. I may have left out something..

Comment: You are seeing a warning that the numerical integration isn't achieving the specified accuracy at some points.  The error is small compared to the result, but you can try changing the numerical precision if you want. The plots look pretty good, so my advice is to continue with this, get a final result, and then go back and fiddle with precision later to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: I think I've find a way to correct my mistakes, thanks a lot, I discovered new methods of programmation in addition of the correction of my algorithm. I hope I won't take too much time to compute datas now. At least I can compute values of my ELF function so I should be able to table it's values. The only things left I'm asking myself is that, as I am working on wave-functions that should be normalized, do I have to renormalize after having compute the scalar pdct and the inverse FT. I think I need to renormalize befoire computing values of the ELF.
Thanks Craig, and I wish you the best
Théo

Comment: If there are normalization parameters (such as domain size) that appear in derivatives later, I think you  would need to normalize early. If not, wait until the end. C’était mon plaisir. C

Comment: In fact, I can just normalize "first/secondTerm" because due to Plancherell's theorem, the FT is an isometry over (L1)intersect(L2) ( speaking of mathematical ensemble here ). Hence if my functions in k-space are normalized, their inverseFT should be too.